# asp.net web service to interact with database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Sorry Im new to this approach.
I wanted to write various web servers at my sql server using .net c#.
to perform various operations to my database, e.g update customer, delete customer, select customer etc..
I am writing a client side web app (to deploy eventually on a mobile) that will send and retrieve data to these web services.
I am unsure of the methods that allow me to do this from my client that allow authentication and are reasonably secure.
So far I am thinking of Jquery AJAX?

Comment: I used [asp.net web api 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) for my first web service. I do a lot of work in asp.net mvc so the development pattern was familiar which was nice. The link should help you get started.

Comment: Christ, this is broad... @Rahul +1 haha

Comment: Please do not use deprecated frameworks/stacks - jump straight onto Web API/MVC. or Web API / Angular (Client side frameworks)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax will allow you to exchange data between server and client within a page without reloading it. It sends and receives data using HTTP messages.

Setup REST service and add jQuery to HTML page. At this point you have a communication channel. Now you have to think about security model.

You may require client to send username+password or authentication token in every request. You also may place these credentials anywhere within HTTP message (cookie, header, body).

If it's your first experience with ASP.NET, try to use standard Forms Authentication (it stores authentication token in `ASPX_AUTH` cookie) or any .NET builtin authentication models.

See articles below to see examples:

[Security in ASP.NET](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security)

[Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

first Create ASMX File

second Create Class inside or outside the ASMX File

```
 public class NationalityInfo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }// any Other           
    }
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public List<NationalityInfo> LoadNat()
    {
        string Conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GPS_TrackingConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        List<NationalityInfo> NatInformation = new List<NationalityInfo>();
        DataSet ds;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Nationality", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
        }
        try
        {
            if (ds != null)
            {
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            NatInformation.Add(new NationalityInfo()
                            {
                                ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),
                                Name = dr["Name"].ToString()                                    
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return NatInformation;
    }
```

in the client side

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Query.asmx/LoadNat",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Result) {
                Result = Result.d;

                $.each(Result, function (key, value) {
var id=value.ID;
var Name=value.Name;

                });

            },
            error: function (Result) {

            }
        });
```

Note in the client side you get object (Array ) not json

For saving (Get values from client to server)

```
function SaveNat() {
        var Nat = {};
        Nat.ID = txtID.value;
        Nat.Name = txtName.value;
        var NatVar = JSON.stringify(Nat);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Query.asmx/SaveNat",
            data: '{Nat: ' + NatVar + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Saved');
            }
        });
    }
```

Server Save Function

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod]

    public void SaveNat(NationalityInfo Nat)
    {
        string Conn = ""// Your Connection

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
               //Save }
        }
    }
```

as for security you must not sent user name and passwor in plain text it will be visible in the Browser trafic 
you should send it encrypted and decrypt it on your server

Comment: If the OP is new to dev and web services, why would you point to a deprecated stack???